# Working with strings and variables from html forms to php

Tags: php, html, string, syntax, if-statement

I have been struggling with a problem working in both html and php.
in my html, i have a form tag that includes:

```
<input type="text" name="car1" size="4" value="" /> car1
```

In my php, i have this:

```
$car1 = 'my favorite car is ' . $_POST['car1'];
echo $car1;
```

I am trying to figure out a way so that when the user does not input anything into the car1 field in html, echo $car1; will print nothing or blank but when the user does input something, $car1 will echo my favorite car is $car1.

I tried using `if(empty()` and `if(isset()` but i am having issues to make it work for some reason.

Any ideas to do this properly? thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST['car1'])){
$car1 = 'my favorite car is ' . $_POST['car1'];
echo $car1;
}
```

Comment: The only minor problem with this is that `empty("0")` will evaluate to `true`… So if the value of `car1` is `"0"`, the `$car1 = ...` won't get evaluated.

Comment: I somehow didnt have that dot between the string and the variable! thanks for the help!

Comment: @David i know this, the manual says this, but for this instance, as there is no car called "0" it seemed like a valid responce, i used the context provided by the poster to decide the appropriate approach, which is how things should be written.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ($_POST["car1"] !== "") {
    $car1 = "my favourite …";
} else {
    $car1 = "";
}
```

Comment: The only minor problem with *your* answer is that it will throw notices if `$_POST['car1']` does not exist. :)

Comment: Ah, very true! Unless, of course, you're pro enough to be rolling with `error_reporting = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
if (!empty($_POST['car1'])) {
    echo 'my favorite car is ' . htmlentities($_POST['car1']);
}
```

See [here](http://php.net/empty) which values are regarded as *empty*. If you want more control, use something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['car1']) && $_POST['car1'] !== '')
```

You should

- always check whether keys in `$_POST` are `!empty` or `isset` before using them
- always HTML escape user supplied data for output
- use labels:

  ```
  <input type="text" name="car1" size="4" id="car1Input" value="" />
  <label for="car1Input">car1</label>
  ```

Comment: As I noted on Dagon's answer: the only minor problem with this is that `empty("0")` will evaluate to true… So if the value of `car1` is `"0"`, the `$car1 = ...` won't get evaluated.

Comment: @David Sure, in that case use `isset` instead. Depends on what values you regard as "empty".

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["car1"]))
    $car1 = "my favorite car is $_POST["car1"]";
else 
    $car1 = "";
return $car1 //if function or
echo $car1; //if general
```